# Nodejs ppa:Chris-lea/node.js fails

Tags: node.js, makefile, npm, apt-get, launchpad

**Given a `nodejs.makefile` which contains the commands to install nodejs/npm & some npm packages, such:**

```
nodejs:
    sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js   #install fresh nodejs
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
    sudo npm update -g npm                             #refresh npm
    sudo npm install -g topojson jsdom minimist        #install npm modules
    npm cache clean
```

**I then run :**

```
sudo make -f nodejs.makefile
```

**but I get stopped at the `sudo apt-get update` level** (command 2) by the error :

```
...     #some messages here
apt-get update
...       #many other messages there
Ign http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonoomph/openshot-edge/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonoomph/openshot-edge/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
make: *** [nodejs] Error 100
```

After checking, it appears the "**Error 100**" is simply the error message of `sudo apt-get update` failing. But I can't get why this famous `nodejs` install way is actually failing, could it be the launchpad servers being out of order ?

**How to make it works ?**

Answer (score 2):

The project move from Launchpad to NodeSource. Information are [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/chris-lea-joins-forces-with-nodesource) and [here](https://chrislea.com/2014/07/09/joining-forces-nodesource/).

You can do this instead, in the CLI:

```sh
# runs new installer, remove Launchpad repository entry if it exists:
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -    
sudo apt-get -y install nodejs          # install nodejs
sudo npm install npm -g                 # update NPM to latest stable
```

If `sudo apt-get -y install nodejs` fails, try:

```sh
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get -y install nodejs --fix-missing
```

Answer (score 0):

There are now [official instructions from joyent](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager) (primary nodejs backer). For Ubuntu:

```sh
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm                               # clean up the place
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -     # add repository
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs                              # install both nodejs & npm
```

For other unix distributions, osx and windows see the link.